# How to preserve value of one column based on other column values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, relational-database

I have a requirement wherein I will be getting records which I need to insert into a database (`MariaDB 10.3`) table wherein for each record I have 2 base values viz. `name` and `amount` and one processed value viz. `action` (imagine this `action` is something acted upon by user from UI).

```
+---------+--------+----------------+----------------+
| name    | amount |    action      |  created_at    |
+---------+--------+----------------+----------------+
| Akshay  | 1000   |   processed    |  2019-08-01    |
+---------+--------+----------------+----------------+
```

Now, what I want to achieve is when next time I receive a record with `name` and `amount` which already exist in the table, then populate `action` by automatic reference to the previous entry from this same table whose `name` and `amount` match.

And if `name` and `amount` combination does not exist in the table, then do not populate `action`.

Desired end result is depicted in structure below:

```
+---------+--------+----------------+----------------+
| name    | amount |    action      |  created_at    |
+---------+--------+----------------+----------------+
| Akshay  | 1000   |   processed    |  2019-08-04    |
| Akshay  | 1001   |                |  2019-08-03    |
| Saanvi  | 1000   |                |  2019-08-02    |
| Akshay  | 1000   |   processed    |  2019-08-01    |
+---------+--------+----------------+----------------+
```

Any clues how can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: 1) Setting the 2nd & subsequent `action` to processed is plain wrong.  Why not set it to "duplicate" ?  2) Why don't you simply disallow duplicates ... or do you want to track the fact that you are receiving duplicates ?

Comment: @PerformanceDBA Yes I want to have duplicate records in. Possibly I may soft delete the previous record. But the question is simplified to help understand things clearly.

Comment: It seems your inserting app is unable to detect dupes, which is the causative problem.  The *Relational Model* prohibits dupes.  Therefore whatever we come up with has to allow dupes, and thus be ugly as sin.  The simple answer is, add an index on (name, amount) and thus prevent dupes.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS db.SP_CREATE_VALUE;
CREATE PROCEDURE db.`SP_CREATE_VALUE`(IN `in_name` VARCHAR(50), IN `in_amount` INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE numAlreadyExists INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE strExistingAction VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT "";

  SET numAlreadyExists=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE name=in_name AND in_amount=in_amount);
  IF (numAlreadyExists >0) THEN
    SET strExistingAction=(SELECT action FROM table_name WHERE name=in_name AND in_amount=in_amount ORDER BY table_id DESC LIMIT 1);
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO table_name
  name=in_name,amount=in_amount,action=strExistingAction;
END;
```

And then when you want to create a new record, simply...

```
CALL SP_CREATE_VALUE('Akshay',1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  For instance:

```
select name, amount,
       max(action) over (partition by name, amount order by date) as action,
       date
from t;
```